# Generic Sites in Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess

I'm running a WordPress site and I want to display (besides the regular articles) some automatically generated content. For example, a usual URL looks like mysite.de/review/[title]

However, I have a list of stored data and I want WordPress to display them as well, without adding sites for it.

For example: mysite.de/pc should display ALL available games tagged with "pc". These data are not stored in WordPress, they are in another database (on the same server).

So, if I try to access mysite.de/pc it throws an 404 (which is correct, since there is no content to be displayed). My question is: how can I add generic sites?

Comment: The wordpress is not fully automatic, you probably will have to have a plugin that does this (access another database). But I do not know what you mean by "generic".

Comment: Well, i can perform my php-code in a snippet, that is not the problem. But i have to have a site where to put this code in. 
So, lets say: I have my site:

mysite.de/pc -> this displays all pc games
now i click on 'minecraft'
the new url is mysite.de/pc/minecraft
now i click on 'downloads'
... 
I want wordpress to automagically display the correct content, but i need to have at least one site, which performs pure PHP, right?

Comment: The pages in wordpress are dynamic, you have to search for something "how to create a plugin for wordpress".

Comment: but they are only dynamic, if there IS a site available. If I write an article and publish it, it is (by default) displayed in the specific spot. But in my case, i don't have a specific file to display: If i have an url like mysite.de/pc/minecraft/tipps, i have to add a functionallity, which handles the request. By default, this site will throw an 404. What I want is to get this from the url: get all tipps from the game minecraft on the plattform pc and show it on a "default" site. Its hard to explain, I'll set up an example this evening. Thank you btw, Guilherme Nascimento :)

Comment: I know what you said, but that's what the plugins do, is to increase the functionality of wordpress plugins in wordpress can handle urls too (with the help of the "rewrite"). :)

Comment: There are plugins that allow you to execute PHP within a page. Search for "Exec PHP" or "Embed PHP". I have never tried it myself, and there are security implications so I cannot recommend any particular one.

Comment: This should probably be moved to http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

If you have a script called pc.php on your public web folder, a call to http://mysite.de/pc will execute that script instead. This will be totally disconnected from your Wordpress site, so it will have to include all the HTML/CSS branding as well as the games list.

It is quick and nasty, but saves you having to delve into bespoke Wordpress plugins.

Comment: yeah exactly, that is more what i was talking about. Exactly. So somehow i have to include the HTML/CSS. But if its out of the WordPress Scope, i can't display the navigation (just for example) properly, right? There is no way, i can "include" my game-list in the default layout?

Comment: If you wanted to display your navigation, it'd have to be hard-coded. By forsaking the wordpress DB and framework, you lose control of all of the functions provided for getting navigation, page stuff, etc. But I mean, this is a good way to do it quick and dirty.

Comment: Well, okay, o got that, i think. But that still leaves the question open: if a user types mysite.de/psx and i don't have a site (psx.php), there should be a "default" page, IF there is a platform called psx. If not, show the regular 404. So I think there should be something like a fallback-site?

Comment: Just as an example: If I would use an url-manager, i could say: /psx/mygame/tips - 
That could call the psx-controller with the action mygame with the param tips. Right?

Comment: okay, once more to sum it up:
mysite.de/pc should display a site (in my theme, the usual content area). the content should be something like: SELECT * FROM `tbl` WHERE platform = 'pc'. 
I would need one site, which handles the request, perform an action and output the result in the specific area